# How to skip requesting access token in Flickr again?

Tags: android, flickr

I'm building flickr api to upload photos! Every time I run my application, It goes through the whole process of requesting for access token! I want if the user has authorize my app, then she don't need to authorize it again. How can I handle access token for this scenario as well as how to handle expire access token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is save your access token into your shared preferences. Then the next time your app loads you could read it from your shared prefrences and use it in your authentication. If it turns out that the token has expired then simply call your method for getting a token and save it over the expired one.

Comment: you are saying, I need to redirect my user to flickr for authorization every time my apps load? I need some solution to avoid this thing.

Comment: No what I am saying is the first time your app launches then you ask the user to log in to flickr. When you do this you get a token back that is sent with your transactions to show that you have authenticated with the flickr servers. You can save this token in your shared prefrences so that once you have logged in once the next time you need your flickr token you will have it saved rather than having to ask for a new access token.

Comment: then how to handle a expire access token?

Comment: Well when you try to use a token that has expired you will fail so you can simply then just ask the user to log in again giving them a new token. Then you save this new token and use it for any further requests.